# jQuery post, posting to ashx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ashx

I am trying to save a user comment to my ashx web handler using jQuery `post`. The problem is that the form data does not seem to be posted, they got the value of `Nothing`.

This is a simplified version of my **jQuery code**:

```
$(".thread_container input[type='button'][name='simplecomment_submit']").live("click", function(e) {
    var query = "?action=comment_save";
    var url = "script/ajax/myhandler.ashx" + query;
    $.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            // update comment list
        } else {
            // report error                        
        }
    })
});
```

My **ashx file** looks something like this:

```
Public Class commenthandler : Implements IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim action As String = context.Request.QueryString("action")
        Dim result As String = Boolean.FalseString

        Select Case action      
            Case "comment_save"
                Dim comment As String = context.Request.Form("comment_message")
                ' call save comment here


        End Select

        Return result
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: does firebug shows any erros/activity...

Comment: No, nothing. But when debugging the ashx code I've noticed that only form fields which were NOT fetched through ajax are posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$(".thread_container input[type='button'][name='simplecomment_submit']").live("click", function(e) {

    var url = "/script/ajax/myhandler.ashx";
    $.post(url,
          {$('form').serialize(),action:'comment_save'}, 
          function(data) {
            if (data == "True") {
             // update comment list
             } else {
                // report error                        
           }
    }); <-- you missed a semicolon 
});
```

and the handler part

```
Public Class commenthandler : Implements IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim action As String = context.Request.QueryString("action")
        Dim result As String = Boolean.FalseString

        Select Case action      
            Case "comment_save"
                Dim comment As String = Context.Request.Form.Get("comment_message")

                ' call save comment here


        End Select

        Return result
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**

```
$(".thread_container input[type='button'][name='simplecomment_submit']").live("click", function(e) {

        var url = "/script/ajax/myhandler.ashx";
        var commentText = $("#simplecomment_commenttext").html(); //get the comment text
        $.post(url,
              {commentTxt:commentText,action:'comment_save'}, 
              function(data) {
                if (data == "True") {
                 // update comment list
                 } else {
                    // report error                        
               }
        }); 
    });
```

and in the handler do

```
Dim action As String = context.Request.QueryString("commentTxt")
```

Comment: I belive that context.Request.QueryString["action"] is not valid vb.net code?

Comment: Thanks for your input - the semicolon were a typo when submitting the question, the `Context.Request.Form.Get(name)` should be equivalent to `Context.Request.Form(name)` (and it does give the same result of Nothing, I've tested). Might have to modify my code to use the `$.ajax({type: 'POST'...` call instead

Comment: do you get the value of `context.Request.QueryString("action")
`

Comment: yes, that is okay. If I debug the value of `comment` after `Dim comment As String = Context.R....` it gives `Nothing`

Comment: try this `context.Request.QueryString("comment_message")
`

Comment: I should mention that the `comment_message` is written like this in the html code: `<textarea id="simplecomment_commenttext" name="simplecomment_commenttext" cols="68" rows="3"></textarea>` AND that the <textarea> is added to the DOM via a jQuery ajax call.

Comment: @3nigma let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2265/discussion-between-muleskinner-and-3nigma)

Comment: Thanks, the approach in your answer works. Still not sure why .serialize() fails on dynamical added fields - markup should be valid